# How to get parent records based on child records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a Rails 3.2 web app and I need some help to construct a SQL-query.
In my app I got users, projects and tasks. Users are assigned to tasks via a join table called assignments.

I need to get a list of all the projects that got tasks that the selected user is assigned to.

**Project**

```
has_many :tasks
```

**Task**

```
has_many :assignments
has_many :users, :through => :assignments
```

**User**

```
has_many :assignments
has_many :tasks, :through => :assignments
```

**Assignment**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :task
```

How can I contruct this query in the most efficient and best practise way?

**Update**

This is how I finally solved it:

```
def index
 tasks = current_user.tasks.joins(:project)
 @output = tasks.map{|task| task.project}.uniq 
end
```

Comment: Very clever implementation of ´joins´... it really cuts down on verbosity. I'll need to keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first specify the `:uniq` option on the `has_many` association, which should return a unique list of user-associated tasks:

```
# app/models/user.rb
has_many :tasks, :through => :assignments, :uniq => true
```

Then, iterate through the tasks and compile an array of all parent projects:

```
tasks = User.first.tasks
projects = []

tasks.each do |task|
    projects << task.project
end
```

Finally, remove all duplicate projects from the array:

```
project.uniq! #=> array of `Project` objects
```

Comment: Perfect! I had to do this though:  projects << task.project

Comment: How can I change the query so I don´t have to make a SQL select (to get project) for each task?

Comment: Quite frankly, I'm not sure that you can. There are several limitations in using ActiveRecord (among others, I'm sure) as an ORM. Because `tasks` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, which is – in practical terms – an array, all you can do is to iterate through and query each member. AFAIK, ActiveRecord doesn't provide any methods to automatically query each member of an array and collect what's returned into a separate `ActiveRecord::Relation`. So basically, you're left to manually iterate through `tasks` yourself.

Comment: Seeing as this answer helped to resolve your question (with a small modification to the task/project lookup, as you duly noted), would you kindly consider accepting it as correct?

Comment: Accepted! Thanks! I have made an update to my question with a small change from your code.

Comment: If a user has more than a couple of thousand tasks, this approach could prove problematic?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big your list of tasks is (this would be inefficient for large lists), you could do this:

```
Project.where("id in (" + tasks.collect(&:project_id).join(",") + ")").uniq
```

This returns the projects (without duplicates) for the tasks in *tasks*.

Edit - For 500 children, this took 0.001977577 seconds this way, and 0.799814631 seconds the way above (via tasks.map).